# Set theory basics exam

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

I have a question about this, we had this on our exam.

Let be $f:A \to B$   a function. Prove next statements or give an example against it.

(i):  if $A$ is countable,  then $f(A)$ is also countable.

I gave a counter example: sequences.
f:  natural numbers into real numbers.

But I got zero points.

(ii): if $B$ is countable,then $f^{-1}(B)$ is also countable.

I tried to prove with claiming that  $f^{-1}(B)$ is a subset of $B$ and so it would mean it's countable. But I am not sure,can anyone help me with it?

Comment: For the identity map, $f(\mathbb{N})=\mathbb{N}$, not $\mathbb{R}$. And you've score zero since it is indeed true..

Comment: "But I gave a counterexample..." No, you didn't. You only say that $\;f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb R\;$ , you don't give explicitly what $\;f\;$ is. To write "sequences" there doesn't help at all. BTW, this claim is true. (ii) Why would $\;f^{-1}(B)\;$ be a subset of $\;B\;$ ?? This could *probably* be true if you have a function with the same domain and the same codomain, but we don't know that... BTW, this claim is false.

Comment: Well real sequence is a function that creates a real number for a natural,....natural is countable,real isn't this a counter example?

Comment: So can you maybe give me some help with proving it then?

Comment: @user246608 So you mean that your $\;f\;$ **is a** sequence? But then a sequence is countable, of course, so how's that a counterexample?

Comment: Oh i see...sequence is also countable,my bad. So how can i prove first statement? And what is a counter-example for 2nd statement?

Comment: If uncountably many elements in $A$ map to countably many elements in $B$, then the second statement would be false. I'm not sure if this is a valid example, but $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}, f(r) = \lfloor r\rfloor$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets and let $f\colon A\rightarrow B$ be a function. Then you can co-restrict $f$ to its codomain, i.e. consider the function $f^{\vert f(A)}\colon A\rightarrow f(A)$ sending $a\in A$ to $f(a)\in B$. Now, by definition, this map is onto, hence the cardinality of $f(A)$ is at most the cardinality of $A$. In particular, if $A$ is countable to start with, then $f(A)$ has either finite cardinality or is in bijection with the natural numbers (this may exactly mean that $f(A)$ is countable, according to the definition of being countable that you have, that is, according to whether a countable set can be finite or not in your definition).

As for the second question, given again any function $f\colon A\rightarrow B$ between two sets, by definition of function and of inverse image, $f^{-1}(B)=A$. Thus, in general there is no hope that $f^{-1}(B)$ is countable if $B$ is such to start with. Take, for example, the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ sending every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ to $0\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas for you to develop:

(i) Here, define $\;h:A\to f(A)\;$ by $\;h(a):=f(a)\;,\;\;a\in A\;$ . Show that $\;h\;$ is surjective (onto), which means $\;\text{card}(A)\ge\text{card}(f(A))\;$

(ii) What about $\;f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb N\;,\;\;f(x)=0\;\;\;\forall\,x\in\Bbb R\; $ ?

Comment: I guess we posted the answers almost simultaneously and I did not notice yours while giving mine. It's funny to see how close they are :)

Comment: @MarcoVergura Indeed so. Remarkably similar, and they were posted at the same time. Let us leave both of them so that the OP and others can see both.